# xcode simulator not coming up - reinstall possible?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I ran out of disk space and had to clean up the folders on my hard disk.  After the cleanup, when I run Xcode, the simulator is not coming up.  I am not able to select a simulator to run,  on 
Xcode.  Most likely I deleted some folder required by simulator, in my cleanup.  Xcode runs onto the device correctly. Anybody came across such a situation?

I deleted my Xcode and re-installed, but that did not solve the issue.  As I can see, Simulator is a separate application (since we can close simulator without closing the Xcode).  Is it possible to re-install Simulator alone?  Or any other solution to get back my IOS simulator?

I know this is not a programming question, still hope can be posted here.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show what happens when you open up iOS Simulator.app.  Anything in ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/*.log?

Comment: I tried the solution by @iCMS below and it worked.  Missed to check this folder before that.  Sorry about that.  Thanks anyway for your time.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I was able to delete my simulator devices and re-install them by following this excerpt written for a user that was missing their simulator:

Open the Xcode > Open Developer Tool > iOS Simulator menu (if you get a pop up error just dismiss it).
Once in the Simulator go to Hardware > Device > Manage Devices.
Delete everything listed under simulator.
Reboot your machine.
After that navigate back to Manage Devices in the simulator and click the plus to add back your simulators. Then the iOS 8 simulators will show up. Hope that also helps you.

Here is where it came from:
http://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/2b9j2p/xcode_6_missing_ios_8_simulator/

Comment: I updated my answer, hopefully this will help you. If not I saw other possible solutions I can post.

Comment: Thank you.  This worked perfectly.  In my case, when I opened the device manager in IOS Simulator, the device list was empty.  I could add all simulators one by one by clicking the + button on the bottom left of that window. Thanks again.  Really helped.

Comment: You're a life saver. I can't believe apple published xcode 6.2 with a flaw of this size...

Comment: You may need to remove devices manually instead. Go to "/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/", delete any devices, restart machine, then add any simulator devices back in same way mentioned above.

Answer (score 28):

This will delete all simulator info and get you back to the point where you can use Xcode/Preferences/Components to re-download the simulators and start from scratch:

1. Quit Xcode, Simulator, Instruments, etc.
2. Run in Terminal: `sudo killall -9 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService`
3. Run in Terminal: `sudo rm -rf ~/Library/*/CoreSimulator`

Thanks to Apple Dev Forum response https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/13718

Comment: I had to also delete (rename) /Library/Developer and then after quitting Xcode and logout/login from macOS, Xcode would ask me to install required components again. After that, I had all current Simulators available.

Comment: I have a similar problem, uninstalling Xcode 10.1 from Apps folder and installing it again from App store, I lost almost every simulator, and after executing this commands in terminal, I recovered all the simulators of iOS 12.2

Answer (score 4):

For Everyone having an issue with the Simulators today in Xcode just go to ***Window/Devices and Simulators*** and delete under the Simulators Section every Simulator. Then create a new one. Hope this helps.