# iOS Simulator 8.1 SDK missing in XCode 6.2

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, gradle

Developers I'm supporting just got new Macs with XCode 6.2 (Version 6.2 (6C131e)).

In running xcodebuild we're having failures in running against any earlier version of the simulator, even if it's been downloaded, getting:

```
:build
xcodebuild: error: SDK "iphonesimulator7.1" cannot be located.
:build FAILED
```

I go to Xcode -> Preferences and download the iOS 8.1 and 7.1 simulator, but still they don't show when doing an xcodebuild -showsdks:

```
xcodebuild -showsdks

iOS Simulator SDKs:
   Simulator - iOS 8.2              -sdk iphonesimulator8.2
```

Ideas?  I can't flip my whole project & CI pipeline to build against 8.2 just yet, wondering if there's a trick to getting the 7.1 / 8.1 sim working from the command line tools in Xcode 6.2.

Comment: I think you should just update your app to use iOS 8.2 SDK.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think that's our only option at this point to keep the pipeline running.  It just eliminates any automated testing on earlier versions of the simulator.

Comment: A guy opened a bug about this on Apple Developer Forums. Let's see if someone fix the issue.

Answer (score 8):

It looks like Xcode 6.2 is having an issue recognizing any additional simulators:

```
xcodebuild[4554:1175053] [MT] iPhoneSimulator: SimVerifier returned: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=53 "Simulator verification failed."  
UserInfo=0x7fe952514ca0 {
NSLocalizedFailureReason=A connection to the simulator verification service could not be established.,  
NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Ensure that Xcode.app is installed on a volume with ownership enabled.,  
NSLocalizedDescription=Simulator verification failed.}
```

Some in the Apple Developer Forums are experiencing the same issues. A radar has been filed, and one possible solution of:

```
"Finally success by nuking /Library/Deverloper/* and re-installing Xcode."
```

Comment: I faced the same issue.

Comment: On "Finally success..." does this mean that xcodebuild -showsdks returns more than just the 8.2 sim?

Comment: For those of you that (like me) could't fix the issue by reinstalling, read my response below. Looks like simulators are completely detached from the xcode bundle after all...

Comment: A high level explanation with a possible temporary solution has been given in the developer forums:

    "Xcode, xcodebuild, iOS SImulator, Instruments, and anything else that runs something against the simulator runtime first verifies the runtime...
    The problem with xcodebuild is that its identifier is incorrect, so it can't connect to the service...
    That is why (at least in some cases), running Xcode.app or another process to do the verification will fix the problem for xcodebuild."

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer in this thread: [xcode simulator not coming up - reinstall possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27338042/xcode-simulator-not-coming-up-reinstall-possible/27338441#27338441) (the accepted answer). Looks like xcode 6.2 is not "smart" enough to create the simulators on its own. This is why, if you update from 6.1 to 6.2, you won't be able to see ios 8.2 simulators even if you have the sdk, and the same reason why if you do a clean install you can't see any simulator at all, even if you specifically install the simulators in the preferences menu. Cheers for the poorly packaged official bundles!

Answer (score -1):

I found this issue too. But my method is to copy the simulator into the SDKs folder and this work at Xcode 6 earlier versions. After I upgrade to xcode 6.2, I found this method did not work anymore.

Comment: This is not an answer. This should be appended as a comment to original question.

Comment: I get this error too when: 
xcodebuild -project myApp.xcodeproj -scheme myApp -archivePath myApp archive CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="iPhone Distribution"

What is triggering the iPhoneSimulator error? Is it the build for i386 and X86.