# Any way to test apps on iPhone with iOS 8.1 on Xcode 6.2?

Tags: ios8.1, xcode-6.2

I have iPhone with iOS 8.1 on it. I can't update to iOS 8.2, because the latest version is 8.3 and I can't install previous versions. As I can see, iOS 8.1 SDK is missing in Xcode 6.2. Is there any way to run my apps on my iPhone?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28975848/ios-simulator-8-1-sdk-missing-in-xcode-6-2

Comment: @MartijnvanPut, there's no solution to the problem, so I was just asking if anyone has solved it

Answer (score -1):

My experience (4 years ago) was Apple required you to purchase a 1 year developers license for $99.  This will allow you to install your apps on your phone.  Not sure if they've changed it or not or if you are having a different issue beyond my knowledge.

Comment: I have this license, but according to my question I have iOS 8.1, and SDK for this version is missing in Xcode 6.2