# Unable to launch iOS7.1 simulator in Xcode 6.2 instruments

Tags: xcode, ios7, instruments

Code which was working fine in xcode 6.1.1 now fails to launch the iOS 7.1 simulator in xcode 6.2 (but works fine for the iOS 8.2 sim).

Here is the command I am using:

> instruments -t Automation -w /Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/233D1DE0-8660-4D98-8E45-5E0794CF7366 /Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/233D1DE0-8660-4D98-8E45-5E0794CF7366/data/Applications/APPNAME/APPNAME.app -v -l 20

This is the error returned:

> instruments[2274:66214] -[UIAInstrument(UIAInstrument_Simulator) _startAgentForApp:withPID:]: Warning: Automation instrument could not locate sim tool.

That command launches the simulator and briefly shows the app's splash screen, then dumps out.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you install the components when you first updated to Xcode 6.2?

Comment: You could try deleting the simulator as detailed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27338042/xcode-simulator-not-coming-up-reinstall-possible

Comment: Tried deleting and reinstalling all the needed simulators for my testing on both iOS 8.2 and iOS 7.1, but no change in the error results.

Comment: Does the simulator work without your app?

Comment: When I launch the Instruments app with the Automation template, and then specify the target as a 7.1 simulator, the sim launches and the app launches in it, but I get "An error occurred while trying to run the script" in Instruments, with no indication what the error is.

Suspicion: the Automation template is somehow incompatible with the iOS 7.1 simulators and I will have to revert to Xcode 6.1.1

Comment: So I take it the simulator won't run on its own?

Comment: The simulator runs fine, both 8.2 and 7.1 versions.  The app installs into the sim fine.  The app launches and can be used in it fine.  But automation scripts (even the utter simplest ones) will not run in the 7.1 sim under Xcode 6.2; the same scripts run fine under Xcode 6.1.1 and for an 8.2 sim in Xcode 6.2.

Comment: Looks like this is resolved in Xcode 6.3.  However, something has broken with scrollUp() in iOS8.  Arrgh

Comment: Seems like a lot of things have broken, alerts and typeString etc.

Answer (score 0):

You may go to xCode -> Preference -> downloads and see in iOS Simulator 7.1 is downloaded or not, if it is not downloaded then download and install it, it might work for you