# Alamofire multipartFormData.append method raise Fatal error: Call of deleted method

Tags: alamofire

I am using Alamofire and I use Alamofire for the http request and uploading image to the server.

Normally, I use simple http request, but today I checked uploading request.
I got the "Fatal error: Call of deleted method" and App was crashed.

This is my code.

```html
Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
                multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: "image", fileName: "user_image", mimeType: "image/png")
                if let params = params {
                    for (key, value) in params {
                        // This method raise "Fatal error: Call of deleted method"
                        multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
                    }
                }
                
            }, to: path, encodingCompletion: { result in
              
            })
```

The next code does not raise the error.
`multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: "image", fileName: "user_image", mimeType: "image/png")`
But this code raise the error which said "Fatal error: Call of deleted method".
`multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)`

Before today, this code did not raise the error.

I tried these.
First, I upgraded Alamofire 4.7.2 to 4.7.3.
But the result was same.

Second, This codes are defined in embedded frameworks, so I copy this method to App code directory.
But the result was same.

Environment
XCode 9.4.1
Carthage 0.30.1 to install Alamofire

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem.

I reinstalled XCode and Simulator, and fixed the problem.

I referenced these links.
[How to Uninstall Xcode on macOS](https://macpaw.com/how-to/uninstall-xcode-on-macos)
[xcode simulator not coming up - reinstall possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27338042/xcode-simulator-not-coming-up-reinstall-possible/27338441#27338441)